# Можно ли как-то объединить dropzone.js и carrierwave без дополнительной модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У carrierwave есть мультизагрузка через  `mount_uploaders  :avatars`, как можно сделать чтобы файлы через dropzone.js загружались в форму с другими полями?

Controller

```
    def create
      @restaurant = current_user.restaurants.build(restaurant_params)
      if @restaurant.save
        flash[:success] = 'Поздравляем! Ваше заведение создано!'
        redirect_to restaurant_profile_index_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

     def restaurant_params
       params.require(:restaurant).permit(:title, :content, {avatars: []})
     end
```

form

```
 <%= simple_form_for @restaurant, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :title, label: 'Название заведения*' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :content, as: :summernote %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <span>Фотогаллерея</span>
          <%= f.file_field :avatars, multiple: true %>
          <!-- dropzone  -->
          <% @restaurant.avatars.each do |photo| %>
              <%= image_tag photo.url() if @restaurant.avatars?%>
         <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Миграция

```
def change
   add_column :restaurants, :avatars, :json
end
```

Ruby 2.2
Rails 5.0